# Jax rs resources 404 not found errror

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs

I am getting below error while running application in java using jax-rs

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report 
Message /ajavaeeconcurrency/resources/greetUser
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/9.0.30
```

I am using java8 and trying to create restAPI using jax-rs
Below is the code

```
package com.app.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@ApplicationPath("resources")

public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}
```

Below is resource class

```
package com.app.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/greetUser")
public class GreetResource {
    
    @GET
    public String greetUser()
    {
        return "java EE concurrency starts.";
    }
```

This is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>ajavaeeconcurrency</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>ajavaeeconcurrency</finalName>
    </build>
    
    <properties>
    
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
</project>
```

My `artifactId` is `ajavaeeconcurrency` . I am trying to access resource using below `URI`

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ajavaeeconcurrency/resources/greetUser
```

I am getting `404` error. How can I resolve the same

Comment: How are you deploying the code?

Comment: I am simply running application using tomcat.

Comment: So you are deploying a `.war` file to Tomcat? What is the name of the file?

Comment: You  know Andreas I am new to java web. in the above pom.xml it is mentioned as war and artifact id is mentiond as ajavaeeconcurrency. whatever pom details or java code I have used is mentioned above. I dont know if I am missing something. can you please help

Comment: That did not answer my question. When you build, the result is a `.war` file, and you then deploy that to TomcatEE, right? What is the **name** of the file you're deploying?

Comment: If you check the Tomcat log file, is the webapp starting up without error?

Comment: ya there is no error. I have not use maven build yet. I have simply does "Run as server" in eclipse id

Comment: Since your `pom.xml` file doesn't show any Spring dependencies, why did you tag `spring` and `spring-boot`?

Comment: Because spring developer know java very well. And i thought they can help Andreas.

Comment: Don't do that. You only include tags that are relevant to the question. Remove them!

Comment: @Andreas is there anyway to resolve it? I created project from scratch 3-4 times

Comment: @Andreas I will remove the same

Comment: Have you tried following a simple JAX-RS "Hello World" tutorial? Did you get that to work? What is then different between that and your code? Change the "Hello World" code one step at a time until it matches what you want, testing it with every update to see if you broke it.

Comment: I can print hello world when I am creating simple java application. in java web i am facing problem

Comment: I didn't say a simple command-line program, I said a [**JAX-RS "Hello World" program**](https://www.google.com/search?q=JAX-RS+%22Hello+World%22+program), e.g. going through a **Tutorial** to show you how to get started with JSX-RS.

Comment: Tomcat is not an implementation of JavaEE, I would suggest you to use another options like: Wildfly, TomEE... then check logs on bootstraping and paste the error (if any)

Answer (score 1):

I think your URL is http://localhost:8080/resources/greetUser.

URL with artifactId part usually configuried in application server if it need.

Comment: try to add annotation @GET @Path("/") public String greetUser()

Comment: Can you write the same in your answer? i actually did not understand

Comment: @ShwetaMishra hi! are you solve problem? if yes - post the solution :-)